# Card header icon positioned to the right

Tags: ionic2

I am having a little challenge trying to re-position an icon in an ion-card header to the right. Check my code samples and pictures below.

> this is my code

```
...
<ion-card *ngFor="let account of Accounts">
<ion-card-header>      
<span item-left>{{account.title}}</span>
<span item-right><ion-icon (click)="takeAction(account.$key)" name="more"></ion-icon></span>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <h5>Bank: <b>{{account.bank}}</b></h5>
  <h5>Ac name: <b>{{account.acname}}</b></h5>
  <h5>Ac name: <b>{{account.acno}}</b></h5>
</ion-card-content>
```

[image: Click to view picture for the above code]

> but the picture below shows what i would love to achieve

[image: Click to view picture for my expectation]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured out the ultimate solution. It is just adding `style="float:right;"`

```
...
<ion-card *ngFor="let account of Accounts">
<ion-card-header>
    <span style="color:blue">{{account.title}}</span>
    <ion-icon style="float: right;" (click)="takeAction(account.$key)" name="more">
  </ion-icon>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <h5>Bank: <b>{{account.bank}}</b></h5>
  <h5>Ac name: <b>{{account.acname}}</b></h5>
  <h5>Ac name: <b>{{account.acno}}</b></h5>
</ion-card-content>
```

Notice how I placed the ion-header contents into an ion-item element

Comment: I think it might be better creating a single row, then two columns within that, and then on the second column applying some sort of text-right class depending on what bootstrap version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`ion-row`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Row/) and [`ion-col`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Col/) with `col-{width}`.

```
<ion-card-header>
<ion-row justify-content-between>
  <ion-col col-11>      
    <span item-left>{{account.title}}</span>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-1>
    <span item-right><ion-icon (click)="takeAction(account.$key)" name="more"></ion-icon></span>
   </ion-col>
</ion-card-header>
```

They are both components of [`ion-grid`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) which works similar to the grid layout of bootstrap.

Comment: Your answer had an impact, but the icon was placed in the middle of the header when displayed. I am thinking of a better approach, so that i can have the icon well seated to the right.

Comment: Try using http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Row/#row-attributes maybe `justify-content-end` or `justify-content-around`

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-subtitle color="primary">Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
    <ion-card-title>
      Title
      <ion-icon color="primary" style="float:right" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    </ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    This is some card content
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: use style="float:right" and do NOT use slot="end"

Answer (score 0):

Use a div container and pull that div to right. HTML should look like below:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let account of Accounts">
<ion-card-header>      
<span item-left>{{account.title}}</span>
<span item-right> 
  <div class="pull-right">
    <ion-icon (click)="takeAction(account.$key)" name="more"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</span>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <h5>Bank: <b>{{account.bank}}</b></h5>
  <h5>Ac name: <b>{{account.acname}}</b></h5>
  <h5>Ac name: <b>{{account.acno}}</b></h5>
</ion-card-content>
```

In CSS add following:

```
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the popular [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) module. Just add the following 2 `CSS` properties to the parent element.

```
<ion-card-header>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <h1>Left Content</h1>
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    ...
</ion-card-header>
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can find another tutorial about `flexbox` with a good explanation and some nice, visual appealing examples.
The snippet above results in something like this:

[image]